# When user adds row to UITableView, the new row does not "stay" when returning to the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on an app where the user can estimate various length and width dimensions (area) for better determining required quantities.

I am struggling with a few items, but will address them one at a time...

I would like the user to add as many fields as they like to input the required areas they need calculated... for this I am using a UITableView and a reuseable cell... I have coded to allow the user to add a new row (or as many rows as they like).  Currently the app starts with 3 rows, but if they want to add more they can.

So that "part" is working... the user can add and delete rows at will, however, if a user adds 3 or 4 more rows in the app and then closes the app, the app on return only displays the default number of rows.

My question is... how can the app "remember" those additional rows...so the next time the user enters the app, the new number of rows are always shown and not my default.  I am not currently asking how to save the data or information inside the row, simply how to save the new number of rows for use later on...

I have some screen caps for reference...

You can see I start with the default 3 rows, and allow the user to add more... that does function... however, when I close the app, the default 3 rows show again, forgetting the rows added by the user... any help much appreciated...

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

So now I have the following additional code based on the suggestions posted below...

In controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SodTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[SodTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
//if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set
//and this view is in editing mode.
//Initialize the cell for "Add Row"
//there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
if(indexPath.row >= tabledata.count && [self isEditing]){

    cell.areaNumber.text = @"";

    NSUserDefaults *area = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [area setObject:self.area_Input forKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"];
    [area synchronize];
    NSLog(@"%@",[area valueForKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"]);

}else{ // this tableview is showing table (not in edit mode)

    /*cell.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];*/
    cell.areaNumber.text = tabledata[indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel*label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.5, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    NSString*text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area %ld",(long)indexPath.row+1];
    [label setText:text];
    [label setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.41 green:0.33 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0]];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: label];
}

return cell;
```

}

Where area_Input is a NSString...

I am trying to then show the result here in viewDidLoad

```
tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.area_Input, nil];
```

But it appears as nil when viewing the NSLog... any ideas?

Comment: A simple solution is to store the row count in NSUserDefaults and have the amount of rows be that variable. This will persist through the closing of the app.

Comment: Awesome, I am using NSUserDefaults for other items... didn't you you can do the same with row count... I'll let you know if I can figure it out... Thanks for the lead!

Comment: If you can't get it working let me know and I can take a crack at it when I get a chance. I would advise just creating a new int var and just increase it by one at the same time you add the row, subtract one when you delete a row. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: //number of rows in table
- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //if the current view is in editing mode
    //add an extra row
    int addRow = [self isEditing] ? 1 : 0;
    
    
    NSUserDefaults *saveUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [saveUserDefaults setObject:tabledata forKey:@"new_row_added_by_user"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[saveUserDefaults valueForKey:@"new_row_added_by_user"]);
    [saveUserDefaults synchronize];
    
    return tabledata.count + addRow;
    
}

Comment: Store an array in the user defaults. The number of items in the array tells you how many cells you have and the contents of each index tells you what should be in that row. I would have it be strings, an empty cell would have an empty string which would cause your placeholder text to show. The values the user enters would then persist between runs and if they add enough cells that cells start getting reused you won't have oddness with numbers getting overwritten. (You will need to get updated strings out of the cells to update your array…)

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions... I'm still stuck... Casey West, I'll take you up on your offer, when you have a few mintutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save these cells info in `NSUserDefaults` then in your `viewWillAppear` retrieve these cells and save them to an array that you use to load the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

In case this helps anyone else...

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SodTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[SodTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

//if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set and this view is in editing mode.
//Initialize the cell for "Add Row"
//there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
if(indexPath.row >= tabledata.count && [self isEditing]){

    cell.areaNumber.text = @"";


}else{ // this tableview is showing table (not in edit mode)

    cell.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.areaNumber.text = tabledata[indexPath.row];
    //[cell addSubview:cell.areaNumber];

    NSUserDefaults *save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [save setObject:tabledata forKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"];
    [save synchronize];
    NSLog(@"This number is from cell creation code %@",[save valueForKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"]);

    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel*label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.5, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    NSString*text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Area %ld",(long)indexPath.row+1];
    [label setText:text];
    [label setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.41 green:0.33 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0]];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:14.0f];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: label];

}

return cell;
```

}

Then in viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"+ / -" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addORDeleteRows)];[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];

// Code to adjust the background image used in app based on whether it is an ipad or iphone 4 or iphone 5

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    // iPad code

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [ADVThemeManager customizeView:self.view];

}

tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if([tabledata count]==0){
    //Your array is empty so you have to call it with @"yourKey"
    tabledata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"]];
}

    NSUserDefaults *save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [save setObject:tabledata forKey:@"sod_area_input_by_user"];

numberOfSection = 1;

[myTable reloadData];
```

Now the app will allow me to insert and delete rows as needed...

I think it should be noted that **"tabledata"** is a NSMutableArray

Thanks everyone for your input... much appreciated...